# Dafny flatten set of sets

Tags: dafny

So I'm trying to get all of the elements from a set of sets but am getting the error:

"a set comprehension must produce a finite set, but Dafny's heuristics can't figure out how to produce a bounded set of values for 'x' "

I think it may be to do with the fact that you can't get the cardinality of a set.

Appreciate all help.

```
function flatten(nested: set<set<int>>) : set<int>
    { set x | forall y :: y in nested && x in y :: x }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following will do what you want:

```
function flatten(nested: set<set<int>>) : set<int>
{
    set x, y | y in nested && x in y :: x
}
```

Your definition is quite different. It says something along the lines of "the set of elements such that for all `y` at all of type `set<int>`, `y` is in `nested` and `x` is in `y`." This is typically false (and thus useless) because it requires that `nested` be a finite set that contains *all* sets of type `set<int>`.

Finally, also note that you *can* get the cardinality of a set `S` using the expression `|S|`.